# error attempt to read or write outside of partition

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, grubrescue

I am getting following error after installing Ubuntu 14.04 on laptop.   I have created 3 partitions and installed Ubuntu on primary.

```
error attempt to read or write outside of partition
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

Help is appreciated

Comment: Me too. I have had 14.04 installed for a while. I suspect either `apt-get` or `aptitude` has removed too much.